# XSLT: I cannot put alias tag in src attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

**Updated**

```
<img>
  <xsl:element name="xsl:attribute">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
      src
    </xsl:attribute>
    test.aspx?id=<xslout:value-of select="blah" />
  </xsl:element>
</img>
```

The preceding generates what I need,

```
<img>
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    test.aspx?id=<xsl:value-of select="blah" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

but not sure how yet? Any insights? More concise?

**Original Post**

Help transforming XSL to XSL snippet:

```
<img>
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:text>test.aspx?id=</xsl:text><xslout:value-of select="blah" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

I'm trying to transform this to:

```
<img src="test.aspx?id=<xsl:value-of select="blah"/> />
```

however I'm not getting the `<xsl:value-of select="blah" />` part

Am I thinking about this wrong? Because when I move that exact `xslout` by itself outside `img` tags it generates the correct `xsl:value-of`

Comment: this is going to be xsl to xsl, so I need {blah} to be literally <xsl:value-of select="blah" />

Comment: XML does not allow a tag to nest within another tag.

Comment: so the updated code is as concise as it gets then?

Comment: I don't know, because you only show us snippets instead of a [mcve].

Comment: That's the entire code, believe it or not. Aside from the stylesheet element. I only need to make this image appear.

Answer (score 1):

The output you are trying to create is not valid XML (attributes can't contain `<` and `"` characters).

What you want to generate is

```
<img src="test.aspx?id={blah}" />
```

You could possibly do this with something like:

```
<xsl:template match="xsl:attribute[@name='src']">
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="avt"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xsl:text" mode="avt">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xsl:value-of" mode="avt">
  <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@select"/>
  <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Though it's hard to tell without seeing a more complete description of what you want to achieve (and your example snippet isn't even well-formed XML)

Comment: what I want to generate is another stylesheet that literally looks like this: <img src="test.aspx?id=<value-of select="blah" /> /> if possible.

Comment: If you generated that, it wouldn't be a stylesheet, it would be garbage.

Comment: I updated my OP and was wondering if you had any thoughts if working code could be more concise?